# Transform hard coded initialization values to CSV

Tags: python, parsing, csv, code-generation

Using Python I wanted to extract data rows shown below to a csv file from  a bunch of javascript files which contain hardcoded data as shown below:

```
....html code....

hotels[0] = new hotelData();
hotels[0].hotelName = "MANHATTAN";
hotels[0].hotelPhone = "";
hotels[0].hotelSalesPhone = "";
hotels[0].hotelPhone = 'Phone: 888-350-6432
';
hotels[0].hotelStreet = "787 11TH AVENUE";
hotels[0].hotelCity = "NEW YORK";
hotels[0].hotelState = "NY";
hotels[0].hotelZip = "10019";
hotels[0].hotelId = "51543";
hotels[0].hotelLat = "40.7686";;
hotels[0].hotelLong = "-73.992645";;


hotels[1] = new hotelData();
hotels[1].hotelName = "KOEPPEL";
hotels[1].hotelPhone = "";
hotels[1].hotelSalesPhone = "";
hotels[1].hotelPhone = 'Phone: 718-721-9100
';
hotels[1].hotelStreet = "57-01 NORTHERN BLVD.";
hotels[1].hotelCity = "WOODSIDE";
hotels[1].hotelState = "NY";
hotels[1].hotelZip = "11377";
hotels[1].hotelId = "51582";
hotels[1].hotelLat = "40.75362";;
hotels[1].hotelLong = "-73.90366";;

    var mykey = "AlvQ9gNhp7oNuvjhkalD4OWVs_9LvGHg0ZLG9cWwRdAUbsy-ZIW1N9uVSU0V4X-8";
                var map = null;
                var pins = null;
                var i = null;
                var boxes = new Array();
                var currentBox = null;

                var mapOptions = {
                credentials: mykey,
                enableSearchLogo: false,
                showMapTypeSelector: false,
                enableClickableLogo: false
                }
.....html code .....
```

Hence the required csv output would  be like rows of the above data:

```
MANHATTAN,,,Phone: 888-350-6432 ...
KOEPPEL,,,Phone: 718-721-9100 ...
```

Should I use code generation tool to directly parse the above statements to get the data ?  Which is the most efficient Python method to transform such data contained in thousands of Javascript files into csv tabular format?

**Update:**

Ideally I would like the solution to parse the JavaScript statements as Python objects and then store it to CSV to gain maximum independence from ordering and formatting of the input script code

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a regular expression to pick out all "hotel[#]. ..." lines, and then add all of the results to a dictionary.  Then, with the dictionary, output to a CSV file.  The following should work:

```
import re
import csv


src_text = your_javascript_text
p = re.compile(r'hotels\[(?P<hotelid>\d+)\].(?P<attr>\w+) = ("|\')(?P<attr_val>.*?)("|\');', re.DOTALL)

hotels = {}
fieldnames = []
for result in [m.groupdict() for m in p.finditer(src_text)]:
    if int(result['hotelid']) not in hotels:
        hotels[int(result['hotelid'])] = {}
    if result['attr'] not in fieldnames:
        fieldnames.append(result['attr'])

    hotels[int(result['hotelid'])][result['attr']] = result['attr_val']

output = open('hotels.csv','wb')
csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(output, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
csv_writer.writerow(dict((f,f) for f in fieldnames))
for hotel in hotels.items():
    csv_writer.writerow(hotel[1])
```

You now have a dictionary of Hotels w/ attributes, grouped by the ID in the Javascript, as well as the output file "hotels.csv" (with header row & proper escaping).  I did do things like named groups which really aren't necessary, but find it to be more self-commenting.

It should be noted that if the same group is provided in the Javascript twice, like hotelPhone, the last is the only one stored.

When dealing with this type of problem, it falls to you and your judgment how much tolerance and sanitation you need.  You may need to modify the regular expression to handle examples not int he small sample provided (ie. change in capture groups, restrict matches to those at the start of a line, etc.); or escape newline characters, like those in the phone number); or strip out certain text (eg. "Phone: " in the phone numbers).  There's no real way for us to know this, so keep that in mind.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you will have to do routinely and you want to make the process fully automatic I think the easiest would be just to parse the files using Python and then write to csv using the [csv Python module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Your code could look somewhat like this:

```
with open("datafile.txt") as f:
    hotel_data = []
    for line in f:
        # Let's make sure the line not empty
        if line:
            if "new hotelData();" in line:
                if hotel_data:
                    write_to_csv(hotel_data)
                    hotel_data = []
        else:
            # Data, still has ending quote and semi colon
            data = line.split("= ")[1]
            # Remove ending quote and semi colon 
            data = data[:-2]
            hotel_data.append(data)

def write_to_csv(hotel_data):
    with open('hotels.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                                quotechar='""', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        spamwriter.writerow(hotel_data)
```

Beware that I have not tested this code, it is just meant to help you and point you in the right direction, it is not the complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , But I would like to parse the these statements for maximum independence as suggested in the question update.

Answer (score 0):

If each hotel has every field declared in your files (i.e. if all of the hotels have the same amount of lines, even if some of them are empty), you may try to use a simple regular expression to extract every value surrounded by quotes ("xxx"), and then group them by number (for example, group every 5 fields into a single line and then add a line break).

A simple regex that would work would be `["'][^"']*["']` (EDIT: this is because I see that some fileds (i.e. Phone) use single quotes and the rest use quotes).

To make the search, use `findall`:

```
compPattern = re.compile(pattern)
results = compPattern.findall(compPattern)
```